# Hypernym for "compassion", "malice", "hatred", "love", "inspiration", etc

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

It's not specifically an *emotion*, a *feeling*, or a *state of mind*—it's something else. Anyone have an idea what is is I'm looking for? Maybe if someone could complete this sentence:

> Anger, rage, jealousy, bitterness, malice, hatred, doubt, melancholy, fear, apathy, ambivalence, dread, anxiety, greed, lust, desire, loss, emptiness, corruption, sympathy, belief, conviction, faith, hope, love, compassion, goodwill, trust, understanding, wisdom, empathy, honesty, and openness collectively are ***_*_**_s.

Comment: MW3UDE: Perhaps the word you're looking for is _affects_ : "2 [German affekt, from Latin affectus] psychology   : the conscious subjective aspect of an emotion considered apart from bodily changes.

Comment: Excluding malice, I think they're all [Mettā](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mett%C4%81)

Comment: Based on the definitions I'm finding in my OED it doesn't seem like 'affect' would work. Ones affect has to do with his or her mental disposition, but compassion or malice itself isn't necessarily a mental disposition. I'm looking for a word that defines this class of words, but it's been eluding me for days.

Comment: The word "meme" came to mind, but a meme is a very specific manifestation of this compassion, malice, charity, etc. But maybe there is a word that is hypernymous with "meme" that could work.

Comment: I've expanded the list considerably using the topics of focus that I'm tasked with writing about.

Comment: @3nafish -- I'm willing to use a Sanskrit or Pali word if those ancient geniuses are the only people ever to categorize these types of words under a single heading, but I'd prefer English if possible. I've expanded the list so you can see all of the words I'm looking to include in the unnamed category if you're curious. You'll find that Mettā excludes quite a few more from my list at this point.

Comment: I'm currently considering the possibility that "disposition" is the word I'm looking for. Any thoughts?

Comment: How about temperament?

Comment: @3nafish, some of the words in the list won't fit under "temperaments", such as "inspiration", "corruption", and "wisdom". Though, I think all of these could be considered dispositions, even if the fit isn't exactly tight, it's still a fit. I'm open to a tighter fit for sure though.

Comment: A hypernym for a sub-set of emotional states that you seem to be looking for can only be called a **feeling towards others**. Even in *Pali* it is *tatta* as a broader term, e.g., *samānattatā* English: Impartiality, feeling towards others as towards oneself. *sabbattatā* English: Identification of all beings with oneself, i.e. universal goodwill.

Comment: I have checked some psychology literature and find the phrase *feeling towards others* used there as well.

Comment: Thanks @RegDwighт for the edits. Looks a lot better now. The subject is also much better. I should have thought of that, actually.

Comment: But, @Kris, _inspiration_ is among the words listed. So are _corruption_ and _wisdom_. These don't strike me qualifying as **feelings toward others**. Maybe one more level up along the hypernymous word-chain would get us to what we're looking for. Someone posted **sentiments** as a potential answer, which I think is looking better than **disposition** thus far. But I suspect there's an even better option still.

Comment: Principle. The word I'm looking for is principle: I. Origin, source; source of action. 3. A fundamental source from which something proceeds; a primary element, force, or law which produces or determines particular results; the ultimate basis upon which the existence of something depends; cause, in the widest sense. 4. An original or native tendency or faculty; a natural or innate disposition; a fundamental quality which constitutes the source of action. II. 6. A fundamental quality or attribute which determines the nature of something; essential characteristic or character; essence. OED Ed 2

Comment: Who wants to do the honors so I can mark it as answered and award some rep? Be sure to include the OED quotes. Unless of course there are objections. Is it possible there's a better word?

Comment: I don't like _principle_ very much at all. Definition II.6. might seem like a good fit, but _principles_ are generally thought to be something more like unwavering moral guidelines or immutable laws. I believe most folks would have trouble associating words like _doubt_, _apathy_, _ambivalence_, _corruption_, and _rage_ with the word _priniciples_. "Those are my principles, and if you don't like them... well, I have others." (Groucho Marx)

Comment: But there is a principle behind every concept. Wait, is **concept** the word I'm looking for?

Comment: _Concept_ is no better than _abstract nouns_, I don't think, and certainly not better than _feelings_, _emotions_, or _affections_, which I think come much closer than either _concepts_ or _principles_.

Comment: What about **conditions**? From the OED again: "II. Mode of being, state, position, nature. 9. a. A particular mode of being of a person or thing; state of being." I think every item in the list qualifies as a "particular mode of being of a person or thing; state of being."

Answer (score 2):

Relatively few *base emotions* (Anger, Fear, Sadness, Joy, Surprise, Disgust and/or Contempt [[1](http://forums.philosophyforums.com/threads/the-six-base-emotions-17335.html), [2](http://www.humintell.com/2010/06/the-seven-basic-emotions-do-you-know-them/)]) are on your list, so I suppose you might refer to most of the emotions on the list as *complex emotions*.  Several of the list items that are not emotions appear to be  *[attitudes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attitude#Noun)* (“Disposition or state of mind”), *ie*, instances of *[temperament](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/temperament#Noun)*,  *ie*, “a person's normal manner of thinking, behaving or reacting”.

In addition, some of them have to do with one's  *[tenets](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenet#Noun)* (“opinions, beliefs, or principles held to be true by someone...”),  *[outlook](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outlook#Noun)* (“An attitude or point of view” or
“Expectation for the future”), or  *[worldview](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worldview#Noun)* (“One's personal view of the world and how one interprets it” or “The totality of one's beliefs about reality”, or “A general philosophy or view of life”), or personality.

Comment: It's possible temperament could work. I'll mine some reading material for precedents.

Comment: It's not looking like any of these are quite the match I'm looking for. I'm looking for a word that is hypernymous to all of these, something more general than emotion, attitude, or temperament, yet still hyponymous with them all.

Comment: This is all very good information. Now if we can just move upward hypernymously until we find the word that can categorize all those found under these subdivisions. I was looking at "quality" just a bit ago as a potential candidate.

Answer (score 2):

How about ***sentiment***?

> sen·ti·ment:
>   Pronunciation: \ˈsen-tə-mənt\
>   Function: noun
>   Etymology: French or Medieval Latin; French, from Medieval Latin sentimentum, from Latin sentire
>   Date: 1639
>   1 a : an attitude, thought, or judgment prompted by feeling : ***predilection*** b : a specific view or notion : opinion
>   2 a : emotion b : refined feeling : delicate sensibility especially as expressed in a work of art c : emotional idealism d : a romantic or nostalgic feeling verging on sentimentality
>   3 a : an idea colored by emotion b : the emotional significance of a passage or expression as distinguished from its verbal context
>   synonyms see feeling, opinion

From Merriam-Webster online dictionary

Comment: I like this one better than _dispostion_: sentiment of anger, sentiment of loss, sentiment of trust, etc.

Comment: It's looking better I think. Do you think that inspiration counts as a sentiment?

Comment: @Zahhar: In a way, yes. If something inspires me, then I think it's affecting my sentiments. I'll admit that _sentiment of inspiration_ may not sound quite as natural as some of the others, but you've given everyone a tough nut to crack.

Comment: There's also _wisdom_ and _corruption_, along with a few others that might not fit with **sentiment**. Yes indeed this is turning out to be a much tougher nut to crack than I was anticipating. Though I've enjoyed lurking on this site for a long time, reading the various questions and studying the answers chosen as the best, it took me about a month and a half of pondering this question before I decided to pose it here. :)

Comment: I have no trouble at all with _sentiment of corruption_. For example: _There's a sentiment of corruption in politics._ As for wisdom: _There's a sentiment of wisdom in Professor Hale's classroom,_ meaning the professor dispenses wisdom for life as well as knowledge from the textbook. (I once had a professor like that – one of the best I ever had.)

Comment: Ah wow you're making **sentiment** look a lot better now. What are the chances you could utilize "inspiration" in a similar sentence? How about "faith" and "conviction"?

Comment: The reason I like sentiment, even for "faith", "conviction" and "inspiration", is that there is a fickleness or tenuousness to it.  One can have convictions until something changes their mind and then their sentiments can be something completely different.

Comment: I'm beginning to lean in the direction of **sentiment**, but I'm going to give it more time to see what else shows up here. I'm also partial toward **condition** since I think this word is actually very accurate in a more technical sense. However, both words still have some connotative failings with regard to some of the items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Compassion, malice, charity, love, inspiration are all ***feelings***

> [***feeling***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feeling) : *Emotion; impression.*

I'm not really happy with the definition I've quoted. All the online dictionaries are about the same though and don't quite capture the exact usage here.  Nevertheless the word works well in your sentence.

Comment: None of these can work because I'm looking for a word that can generalize a much broader spectrum of emotions, states, attitudes, tendencies, etc. I'm sure there's a word for all this, but it's really eluding me thus far. I'm sure I knew the word once upon a time.

Comment: @ErinThomas- Well I think you need to give us a broader range of examples then-  some words which are not feelings, but need to be included by your desired word.

Comment: I think I can do this. Here is a list, still being expanded upon as I encounter new ones that I want to work with: Anger, Rage, Jealousy, Bitterness, Malice, Hatred, Doubt, Melancholy, Fear, Apathy, Ambivalence, Dread, Anxiety, Greed, Lust, Desire, Loss, Emptiness, Corruption, Sympathy, Belief, Conviction, Faith, Hope, Love, Compassion, Goodwill, Trust, Understanding, Wisdom, Empathy, Honesty, Openness.

Comment: @ErinThomas- I'm not sure these words are all on the same footing.  *Corruption*, *Faith* and *Belief* aren't cut from the same cloth as the others.  For the rest of them you can say "*a feeling of <your word>*" and it will make sense.

Comment: Yes, they're not all feelings. If they were I could use "feelings" to talk about them collectively. But they ARE all SOMETHING, and something specific. I've encountered the word I'm looking for in the past, but the filing cabinet in my brains is a bit disorganized so I'm having difficulty looking up the word in question. :)

Comment: Ok, good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to remember to comment here if I find what I'm looking for so you can see it, too.

Comment: The obsolete meaning of "affect" is "feeling; emotion", but current psychiatric jargon suggests that M-W's judgment that those two terms are _obsolete_ is significantly premature. "[Affect refers to the experience of feeling or emotion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affect_(psychology)" OTOH, the footnotes to this Wikipedia article suggest that psychological discussions about affect, emotion, & feelings are very technical & require a specialized vocabulary that only psychologists are familiar with. I'll bet it's some German word & not an English word at all.

Comment: I'll take a German word, @BillFranke, if the word I'm looking for doesn't exist in English. :) What do you think of "quality". Yet, all of these words are in fact qualities of something else, so I suppose it's still that something else I'm looking for.

Comment: Hey, what do you think of "disposition"? I was pondering it some and it seems to me that all items could be considered dispositions of one sort or another, whether emotional, mental, philosophic, etc.

Comment: Well, you'd have to change your words to adjectives but then I suppose you could have:  an angry disposition, a jealous disposition, a trusting disposition, a faithful disposition etc.

Comment: Well if I'm going to introduce each of these words as an individual topic, I might be safe in introducing them as "dispositions". Something like, "The following sections will explore the dispositions of anger, ..., doubt, ..., compassion, ..., inspiration, etc." It seems to work to my mind. Any objections?

Comment: @ErinThomas, the definition of *attitudes* that I referred to in my answer sort of treats *disposition* as a synonym, but I think *disposition* generally works better than *attitudes* in your examples just above.

Answer (score 1):

Those are *abstract nouns* (refer to http://www.k12reader.com/abstract-nouns/)

Comment: While this is true, "abstract noun" is much too general. I need to move downward through hyponymy toward something that encompasses only the types of abstract nouns in question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word for the full range of identifiable qualities minds can exhibit.

The nearest I can get is they're all [mental states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_state) in the ["Philosophy of mind"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mind) sense - *a kind of hypothetical state or process that corresponds to thinking and feeling*.

But I do think there's quite a difference between relatively ephemeral "reactions" (*rage, lust, desire*, etc.) and more constant "attributes" (*wisdom, honesty, openness,* etc.). The former are often called *feelings*, the latter, *personality traits* or *characteristics*.

Comment: I've been considering "mental state" or "philosophy of mind", but thus far it just doesn't feel right. It's certainly something I can come back to if nothing better is offered here. Yet, I'm almost certain there is a very specific word that will do the trick. There are nearly a million words in the English lexicon. So I'm sure one, or two together, will do the trick and nicely so.

Comment: On what do you base your faith that English will have a "very specific word"? Mental activity is probably equal in importance to *physical* activity for human beings, and off-hand I can't think there's a collective word for all our physical activities either (unless you just assume *activity* only applies to actual physical activity).

Comment: Well I base it on the somewhat dim memory of having used this word once upon a time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what the OP has stated in comments, most, if not all the provided words, can be [classified as **affections**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aRoget%27s_thesaurus_classification#Class_VI._Words_Relating_to_the_Sentient_and_Moral_Powers). Roget categorises *compassion* under *sympathetic affections* while *malice* is apparently a type of *diffusive sympathetic affection*.

Comment: Ah! I'll dig into this a bit and corroborate your feedback. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: What do you think of "disposition"? Are all of the items listed dispositions?

Comment: I think Roget's *affections* is far too broad a term - it includes such disparate concepts as *ugliness, celibacy, drunkenness, asceticism*, for example.

Comment: @ErinThomas I think disposition is a good fit although it connotes _tendency_ rather than a _determinate_ state. Good luck :)

Comment: Well, if you think about it, any of these items denotes the tendency to act out its own meaning. Right? So compassion is the tendency to act compassionately. Malice is the tendency toward maliciousness. Etc. and so on for the rest. In a way this implies a determinate state in its own right. I'm thinking I'll answer this question with "disposition", but first I'm going to give it a day or so to see what other feedback shows up.

Comment: @ErinThomas- I'd say rather that Malice is the result of a malicious tendency left unchecked.

Comment: That, too, @Jim, but it still seems to work. If you can think of any alternatives that might be an improvement over "dispositions", I'll certainly appreciate seeing them. I also appreciate your feedback thus far. Without the help of you and others I wouldn't even have managed to come to "dispositions" as a possible answer.

Comment: OED ***affection*** a: *An affecting or moving of the mind in any way; a mental state brought about by any influence; an emotion or feeling*; b: *The representation of feeling or emotion*. But even Roget's ***Personal** Affections* section includes things like *taste, vulgarity, fashion*. I think they're just using the word in a very obscure fashion, *faute de mieux*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think rather that all these terms are broad and vague and overlap in nebulous ways (and few of Roget's hypernyms are really accurate). Also, the long list (not in the title) covers so many words that they just don't fit in any one part of Roget's taxonomy.